# redirect to another controller fails in RoR 3.2.13

Tags: redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2, controller

I'm trying to redirect to the index action of another controller once I have accomplished a create in the current controller. But the redirect fails, resulting in a url pointing to the index action in the current controller (which doesn't exist, resulting in a blank page)

Here is my code :

### clients_controller.rb

```
def create
  @client = Client.new(params[:client])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @client.save
      session[:client_id] = @client.id
      redirect_to produits_url
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

### produits_controller.rb

```
def index
  @produits = current_client.produits

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @produits }
  end
end
```

### routes.rb

```
  get "home/index"

  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "inscription" => "clients#new", :as => "inscription"
  match '/a_propos', to: 'application#a_propos'

  resources :sessions

  namespace "admin" do
    resources :clients, only: [:index]
  end
    resources :clients, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  resources :produits
```

### rake routes

```
   home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)        home#index
      log_out GET    /log_out(.:format)           sessions#destroy
       log_in GET    /log_in(.:format)            sessions#new
  inscription GET    /inscription(.:format)       clients#new
     a_propos        /a_propos(.:format)          application#a_propos
     sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)          sessions#index
              POST   /sessions(.:format)          sessions#create
  new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
 edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) sessions#edit
      session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#show
              PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
              DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#destroy
admin_clients GET    /admin/clients(.:format)     admin/clients#index
      clients POST   /clients(.:format)           clients#create
  edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)  clients#edit
       client PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)       clients#update
              DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)       clients#destroy
     produits GET    /produits(.:format)          produits#index
              POST   /produits(.:format)          produits#create
  new_produit GET    /produits/new(.:format)      produits#new
 edit_produit GET    /produits/:id/edit(.:format) produits#edit
      produit GET    /produits/:id(.:format)      produits#show
              PUT    /produits/:id(.:format)      produits#update
              DELETE /produits/:id(.:format)      produits#destroy
         root        /                            home#index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, you need to call the `redirect_to` inside the `format.html` block. However this can be quite ugly, I recommend using `respond_to`. See below:

I strongly recommend naming your class en plain english.

```
Produit => Product
ProduitsController => ProductsController
```

Rails is using a lot of conventions but they are some differences between how french handle pluriels and english does.

Then you should be able to achieve what you want doing the following:

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :products
```

**app/controllers/products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController
  def index
    # your code
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/clients_controller.rb**

```
class ClientsController
  respond_to :html

  def new
    # your code
  end

  def create
    @client = Client.new(params[:client])
    if @client.save
      session[:client_id] = @client.id
      redirect_to products_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Class names and languages are irrelevant, as long as they don't overlap reserved keywords and plurialize with an s, which is the case of « produit ».

Comment: I removed the 'respond_to do |format|...end' as you suggested, and this works.
But this puzzles me since it is generated by scaffold.
So what's wrong with this scaffold code in 3.2.13 ?!

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, you just did not encapsulate your `redirect_to` inside `format.html { }` ;) Considerate accepting the answer if your think it helped you.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it definitely helped since it now works. But I'm not sure I understand your "respond_to :html" outside of controller's actions or what you mean with encapsulate the redirect_to inside format.html { }
Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Read here http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3 and everything will be clear :) Regarding your initial issue, you had to do this `format.html { redirect_to produits_url }` in order to work. Using `respond_to` is easier as you saw.